# Grid view of button dynamically of two button in a row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gridview

I want to create a grid view of buttons which will be created dynamically .and on click of button in grid view different task for every button.how can i do this any help will be appreciate?

Comment: try to using collectionView controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done This Before Using Scroll View This May help you.

```
       int number_of_types = 20; // (no of total buttons )


int btncount=0;
        int number_of_buttons_in_row = 4;
        CGFloat screen_width = 280.0, button_width = 70;

        CGFloat xpadd = (screen_width - ( number_of_buttons_in_row * button_width ))/(number_of_buttons_in_row+1);

        CGFloat x_coord, y_ccord;
        int buttonXOffset, buttonYOffset, buttonWidth, buttonHeight;
        buttonWidth = 57;
        buttonHeight = 57;

        x_coord = 20;
        y_ccord = 70;

        int number_of_rows;

        if((number_of_types % number_of_buttons_in_row) == 0)
            number_of_rows = number_of_types / number_of_buttons_in_row;
        else 
            number_of_rows = number_of_types / number_of_buttons_in_row + 1;

        int number_of_buttons_count = 0;
        for (UIView * view in scrollBack.subviews) {
            if(view.tag!=999 )
            {   
                [view removeFromSuperview];
                view = nil;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i< number_of_rows; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<number_of_buttons_in_row; j++) {

                buttonXOffset = 75;
                buttonYOffset = 58;
                UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                btn.frame = CGRectMake(40, 0, 57, 57);

                x_coord += button_width/2 + xpadd;
                btn.center = CGPointMake(x_coord, y_ccord);

                [scrollBack addSubview:btn];

                buttonXOffset = x_coord - buttonWidth/2;
                buttonYOffset = y_ccord - buttonHeight/2;


                UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(buttonXOffset, buttonYOffset + buttonHeight + 4, buttonWidth+7, 28)];



                btn.tag= btncount;

                [btn setTitle:@"your Title "];
//if titles are in a Array  then you can Use 

    [btn setTitle:[titleArray objectatindex:btncount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


                [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                label.text = [titleArray objectatindex:btncount];






                label.tag = 777;
                label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:11];
                label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
                label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                label.numberOfLines = 0;

                [scrollBack addSubview:label];
                [label release];

                x_coord += button_width/2;
                number_of_buttons_count++;
                if(number_of_buttons_count == 20)
                    break;

                btncount++;

            }
            if(number_of_buttons_count == 20)
                break;
            y_ccord += 120;
            x_coord = 20;



        }
        scrollBack.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, buttonYOffset + 200);



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be insterted in `viewDidLoad` inside your view controller and assumes that you have setup your UISCrollView in interface builder, otherwise you would need to allocate your scroll view inside `viewDidLoad`.

The code will add a variable number of image items to a UIScrollView with 2 columns.

```
UIButton * button = nil;


//The x and y view location coordinates for your menu items 
int x = 0, y = 0;

//The number of images you want 
int numOfItemsToAdd = 10; 

//The height and width of your images are the screen width devided by the number of columns 
int imageHeight = 320/4, imageWidth = 320/4; 

int numberOfColumns = 2; 

//The content seize needs to refelect the number of items that will be added
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, imageHeight*numOfItemsToAdd];
for(int i=0; i<numOfItemsToAdd; i++){
    if(i%numberOfColumns == 0){//% the number of columns you want
        x = 0;
        if(i!=0)
            y += imageHeight;  
    }else{
        x = imageHeight;  
    }
    button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight)];

    //set the center of the image in the scrollviews coordinate system 
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(x, y); 

    //Finaly add the image to the scorll view
    [scrollView addSubview:button];
```

and By giving the Tag to the button with incremental,so that each tag will be assigned to each button and giving then event to the each of the button , you u give your different task in grid view.
in the below

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)mybutton{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you PTSpringBoard sample codefor grid menu detection

https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSSpringboard

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
    for (int i=0; i<totalButtons; i++){

       UIButton* abutton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
       [abutton setTitle:@"Button_Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       abutton.tag=100+i;
       [abutton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [gridView addSubview:abutton];
       //here you need to calculate and set the position for the button
       abutton.center=CGPointMake(calculated_X, calculated_Y);
       [abutton release];

    }

-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)mybutton{
    NSLog(@"%d is the Tag",mybutton.tag);
    //here you do what you want with the indexed button clickes


}
```